# Writing a stored procedure operating on a result set from a SELECT statement

Tags: sql-server, table-valued-parameters

How would one write a stored procedure that takes as input a table value parameter but that table value parameter consists of row with the columns of an existing table?

I could manually create a TVP that matches the table, populate it with a query pass it into the stored procedure but I can't help but think there is smarter way so I don't have to keep my TVP manually synced with my table.

Basically I want to be able to do

```
EXEC MYCOOLSPROC @myTVP = resulting rows of 'SELECT * FROM AWESOME_TABLE WHERE ID > 10 AND ID < 20'
```

Comment: Why not just operate on the row directly? Why do you need to pass it as a reference?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create the tvp parameter in `MYCOOLSPROC` as `READONLY`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MYCOOLSPROC
@bTVP MYTVP READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM @bTVP   
END
```

And this is sample how you use this with MYCOOLSPROC

Declare the TVP variable, insert some values into it
    DECLARE @aTVP MYTVP

```
INSERT INTO @aTVP ( ... ) VALUES ( ... )
```

OR it can be from the result of another Stored Procedure

```
INSERT INTO @aTVP
EXEC AnotherStoredProcedure
```

And then you can pass the `@aTVP` to `MYCOOLSPROC`

```
EXEC MYCOOLSPROC @bTVP = @aTVP
```